# API's similar to GLUTesselator?

Tags: c++, c, api, graphics, tesselation

I'm looking for an API that is open sourced and that can take contours of verticies as input and return verticies of triangles. I would also like it to support different winding rules. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) has a GLU style tesselator, see http://www.openscenegraph.org/documentation/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs/a00854.html#_details for details.

[Visualization Library](http://www.visualizationlibrary.com) also provides a tesselator, see http://www.visualizationlibrary.com/documentation/classvl_1_1_tessellator.html for further information.

Both libraries are open source.

Comment: Unfortunately both of these use GLU to do the work