# Is it OK to use GLUTesselator in DirectX?

Tags: opengl, directx, triangulation, glu, tesselation

*Related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231128/alternative-to-glutesselator), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411328/apis-similar-to-glutesselator)*

In my OpenGL project I use GLUTesselator to split concave polygons (which comes from external source) to triangles, which are fed to OpenGL through VBO after that. Now I'm estimating adding DirectX back-end.

I can use 3-rd party triangulator, but it's not easy to find the suitable one. There is [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/), but it works only with *simple* polygons, having no duplicates, no touching and so on. Otherwise it simply hangs. As my polygons comes from external source, it's not very easy to conform. GLUTesselator works perfect here; from GLU documentation: *Input contours can be intersecting, self-intersecting, or degenerate. Also,
polygons with multiple coincidentvertices are supported.*

I think it is possible to draw polygons without holes with stencil buffer (see [4](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name13)), but this provides no possibilites for caching.

As I see, it was recommended to use GLUTesselator with DirectX (see [5](http://graphicsbb.itgo.com/solutions/extrude.html), 11 years ago). Is it true that GLUTesselator is pure software library? Is it OK to use it with DirectX, or there are better possibilities around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GLU Tesselator is a geometry/math only library. You can use it without initializing OpenGL, so it works fine alongside DirectX.